# How is this line in JS?

Tags: plugins, unity-game-engine

```
((PlayGamesPlatform) Social.Active).SignOut();
```

It's part of the [Google Play Games plugin for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming that's a typecast, unityscript version would be something like

`(Social.Active as PlayGamesPlatform).SignOut();`